# buildbot: How to set boolean property using Interpolate?

Tags: buildbot

I try to set a new Boolean property using Interpolate:

```
'new-property':Interpolate('%(prop:old-property:~False)s')
```

but 'new-property' gets the value 'True' (string) instead of the value True (Boolean).
How can I set the new property to Boolean value?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't do such a thing with Interpolate which is supposed to work only with strings http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-properties.html#interpolate
An other solution could be to use string as a boolean (e.g. not empty string = True, empty string = False. Could that work for you?

Comment: My solution is to use the strings 'True' and 'False' instead of boolean values.

Comment: Can you be more precise about that?
Like you do a string comparison?

Comment: Correct. check if new-property == 'True'